# Exploded Pie Chart on click with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

Can someone direct me to any resource to make exploded pie chart on click with d3.js just like we have the pie charts in kendo ui. I can't use kendo as I have very specific requirements that Kendo UI can't  fulfill. I have made my pie chart with all the required functionality but can't really find any resource to make it explode on click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [Michael Bostock's examples gallery](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) (he is the author of D3) as a starting point when developing a new D3 visualisation.

Eg. Use the code sample from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235.

Edit: To add the "explosion" you just need a little translation applied to each segment.

```
var explode = function(x,index) {
  var offset = (index==5) ? 80 : 0;
  var angle = (x.startAngle + x.endAngle) / 2;
  var xOff = Math.sin(angle)*offset;
  var yOff = -Math.cos(angle)*offset;
  return "translate("+xOff+","+yOff+")";
}

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); })
    .attr("transform", explode);
```

See it in a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/L4pyk79e/2/

Comment: Mike's gallery doesn't have an example for exploded pie charts. My starting point of d3 charts was his gallery. I have made a lot of custom improvement to the existing example to suit my needs but I m really struggling for exploded pie

Comment: Updated with the adjustment you require.

Answer (score 0):

You could use D3pie which is based on D3: http://d3pie.org/

Comment: Thanks....I will try this..but can I add custom features to the chart if I use this library?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish ofcourse, you only mentioned "exploding". But it has callbacks for click, mouseover and mouseout events so you could attach your own behaviour on those events.